# Linq to SQL with unique index using ignore duplicate keys option and an Identity column

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

```
_db.Comments.InsertAllOnSubmit(comments);
_db.SubmitChanges();
```

There is a unique index on this table with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`, i know that i'm inserting duplicates i just want to ignore them, i'd rather not check each record manually, as this will be slower.

It throws the following:

InvalidOperationException:
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.

I'm assuming this is because the value returned to L2S for the primary key field (it's an IDENTITY Column) is null. To me this seems almost like a bug.

Anybody got any ideas, other than individual insert with try/catch or manual checking?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the property to be nullable. This seems more like a work around than a solution. You can change it in the generatedc code (bad idea) or create a subclass and the new keyword.

int? ID;

Comment: I don't really want to change the generated code, how can i do it with a subclass and still maintain the normal functionality of having linq to sql map the id property? For now, i'm just submitting 1 at a time and catching exceptions :/